# How do I create a navigational webpage that doesn't have to re-retrieve information on each load?

Tags: html, load, navbar

I am creating a collection of HTML documents that is connected with a navbar. It is really simple, but so far, the links on the Nav-Bar just link to other HTML Pages.

All of these pages are very data-heavy, and use Javascript to process through almost a terabyte of data, so I can't have it so that when I need to go back and forth, the page reloads all of the data.

Any good ways to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You might look into using localStorage to store as much of the data on the user's machine as you can. It won't store a whole terabyte, though.

You will probably also want to incorporate ajax, so your script can first check if the data is in localStorage and then download it asynchronously if it isn't.

Comment: All of the data is already in the local storage. What I do is use a script that parses the data from some servers (~1 tb) and then this creates a bunch of text and JSON files on the local machine.

What I was sort of asking was if there is any framework or built-in method to sort of "hide" the current page being displayed when going to another link, so it won't have to reload all of the data again.